# Using ADFv2 Validation activity to check minimum size of Virtual Directory of Azure BLOB dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory

ADFv2 Validation activity using Azure BLOB dataset has a property called **Minimum size**. I would like to validate that a certain virtual directory for a given Azure blob storage has total file size specified in the **Minimum size** field. For that I have tried leaving the 'File' field of the connected dataset as blank but it didn't work. The activity succeeded even though there was an empty file in the virtual directory. Then again made the 'File' field as * and then the validation activity just kept running, never succeeded. How do I achieve this?

Comment: tried changing type of dataset from delimited text to binary etc but it didn't change the behavior of the activity

Comment: Hi Dhiraj, I tested and have the same problem with you. I think we can't achieve that for now. As you know, the document is not clearly about the properties. The best way is to ask Azure support for more details and helps. Hope my answer can be helpful for  you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I tested and found that: **Minimum size** only works for specified file, like bellow:

[image]

[image]

Parameter with dynamic content also doesn't support:

[image]

[image]

If we set the **Minimum size** value is bigger than the file size, the validation activity will always being in progress.

I think there are the limits about the validation activity. So we can't achieve that. We could call the Azure support to get more helps.

Hope this helps.